# Include many visualForce page into one

Tags: visualforce, pdf, include

I want to include many visualForce page into a single with `apex:repeat`. the pages are all rendered as a pdf, because what I want to obtain is like a big pdf that includes many pdf that can be generated from records.

Here is my visualForce for now:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false"
       standardController="Asset" recordSetVar="Asset" extensions="AssetElectricCertificationController">

    <apex:repeat value="{!assetsToShow}" var="SingleAsset">
        {!SingleAsset.Name}
        <apex:include pageName="AssetElectricCertification"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

the `assetsToShow` is juste a `List<Asset>` that my controller chose.

`AssetElectricCertification` is a visualForce page shown as pdf that can be generated if I go on each Asset record of my list. But I want to have them all on the big pdf.

I have two problems. The first one is that the `<apex:include>` component generate the error :`Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Name'` which is not resolvable by changing my repeat variables names.

The other broblem is how will the `<apex:include>` know how to generate a page from a record from my repeat? There is know way of passing a variable like a recordId tho tell a `<apex:include>` the  record from wich it should be generated. I think it use `apexPages.currentPage()` to generate a page normally, but the documentation doesn't talk about that at all.

Thank you

Comment: Not tried including a page within a page...why not make the child pages an apex component? I imagine you would need to be careful of view state size here as well.

Comment: apex: components are the way to go here